# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function chat.server.send

Tags: javascript, signalr

When I try and complete the following [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) I get the above error here:

`chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());`

The `signalr/hubs` scripts are loaded

```
<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message. 
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page. 
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.  
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: auto generated signalR hub

```
/*!
 * ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.0.3
 * http://signalr.net/
 *
 * Copyright Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache 2.0
 * https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 *
 */

/// <reference path="..\..\SignalR.Client.JS\Scripts\jquery-1.6.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.signalR.js" />
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />
    "use strict";

    if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
    }

    var signalR = $.signalR;

    function makeProxyCallback(hub, callback) {
        return function () {
            // Call the client hub method
            callback.apply(hub, $.makeArray(arguments));
        };
    }

    function registerHubProxies(instance, shouldSubscribe) {
        var key, hub, memberKey, memberValue, subscriptionMethod;

        for (key in instance) {
            if (instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                hub = instance[key];

                if (!(hub.hubName)) {
                    // Not a client hub
                    continue;
                }

                if (shouldSubscribe) {
                    // We want to subscribe to the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.on;
                } else {
                    // We want to unsubscribe from the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.off;
                }

                // Loop through all members on the hub and find client hub functions to subscribe/unsubscribe
                for (memberKey in hub.client) {
                    if (hub.client.hasOwnProperty(memberKey)) {
                        memberValue = hub.client[memberKey];

                        if (!$.isFunction(memberValue)) {
                            // Not a client hub function
                            continue;
                        }

                        subscriptionMethod.call(hub, memberKey, makeProxyCallback(hub, memberValue));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies = function () {
        var proxies = {};
        this.starting(function () {
            // Register the hub proxies as subscribed
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, true);

            this._registerSubscribedHubs();
        }).disconnected(function () {
            // Unsubscribe all hub proxies when we "disconnect".  This is to ensure that we do not re-add functional call backs.
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, false);
        });

        proxies.chathub = this.createHubProxy('chathub'); 
        proxies.chathub.client = { };
        proxies.chathub.server = {
            message: function (name, message) {
                return proxies.chathub.invoke.apply(proxies.chathub, $.merge(["Message"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             }
        };

        return proxies;
    };

    signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
    $.extend(signalR, signalR.hub.createHubProxies());

}(window.jQuery, window));
```

Comment: This error implies that `chat.server` is not set properly. You need to post your code.

Comment: The code is as the tutorial as was explained in question, i have updated the question

Comment: Why are people voting to close this?

Comment: Because as originally written it didn't have enough information to answers.

Comment: Yes it did. If you mean people had to click on a link to see the full code then ok. Rules, rules, rules eh? Where is the community spirit? Oh thats right you get points for pointing stuff like this out

Comment: For all we knew, you didn't copy the code exactly as written. We need to see what YOU are doing, not what's written in the tutorial.

Comment: what does the hub class look like?

Comment: chathub is automatically generated by signalR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the auto-generated hub script, your (only) server-side handler is called `message`, not `send`. So you probably changed the method name in the hub from `Send` to `Message` (since in the tutorial, it is actually send):

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
{
    // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
}
```

So in your case, instead of

```
chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
```

you need

```
chat.server.message($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
```

(or you need to create a `send` method in the hub as above).